# Angular2 on focus event to add class

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular-directive

I'm looking to update an Angular 1 app to Angular 2 and am having an issue with one of my old directives.

The idea is simple. When an input field is focused a class should be added (md-input-focus) and another be removed (md-input-wrapper). Then this process should be reversed on "blur" event - i.e. focus lost.

My old directive simply included the lines

```
.directive('mdInput',[
    '$timeout',
    function ($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                ngModel: '='
            },
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                var $elem = $(elem);
                $elem.on('focus', function() {
                      $elem.closest('.md-input-wrapper').addClass('md-input-focus')
                })
                .on('blur', function() {
                 $(this).closest('.md-input-wrapper').removeClass('md-input-focus');
                })
             }
```

etc...

I obviously have the classic start to my directive but have run out of.....skill

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Renderer, Input} from 'angular2/core';

@Directive({
      selector: '.mdInput',

})

export class MaterialDesignDirective {
      constructor(el: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer) {
           // Insert inciteful code here to do the above
      }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

The HTML would look like (before the input element was focused):

```
<div class="md-input-wrapper">
   <input type="text" class="md-input">
</div>
```

and then

```
<div class="md-input-wrapper md-input-focus">
   <input type="text" class="md-input">
</div>
```

after.

The input element is the only one which can receive a focus event (and therefore the target for the directive) however the parent `<div>` requires the class addition and removal.

**Further help**

[Please see Plunker for help/explanation](https://embed.plnkr.co/vXMf2wGRsjg5MCJmPrGY/) - would be great if someone could help

Answer (score 6):

**Update**

```
@Directive({selector: '.md-input', host: {
  '(focus)': 'setInputFocus(true)',
  '(blur)': 'setInputFocus(false)',
}})
class MaterialDesignDirective {
  MaterialDesignDirective(private _elementRef: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer) {}
  setInputFocus(isSet: boolean): void {
    this.renderer.setElementClass(this.elementRef.nativeElement.parentElement, 'md-input-focus', isSet);
  }
}
```

**Original**

This can easily be done without `ElementRef` and `Renderer` (what you should strive for in Angular2) by defining host bindings:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Renderer, Input} from 'angular2/core';

@Directive({
      selector: '.mdInput',
      host: {
        '(focus)':'_onFocus()',
        '(blur)':'_onBlur()',
        '[class.md-input-focus]':'inputFocusClass'
      }

})

export class MaterialDesignDirective {
      inputFocusClass: bool = false;

      _onFocus() {
        this.inputFocusClass = true;
      }

      _onBlur() {
        this.inputFocusClass = false;
      }
}
```

or a bit more terse

```
@Directive({
      selector: '.mdInput',
      host: {
        '(focus)':'_setInputFocus(true)',
        '(blur)':'_setInputFocus(false)',
        '[class.md-input-focus]':'inputFocusClass'
      }

})

export class MaterialDesignDirective {
      inputFocusClass: bool = false;

      _setInputFocus(isFocus:bool) {
        this.inputFocusClass = isFocus;
      }
}
```

I tried it only in Dart where it works fine. I hope I translated it correctly to TS.

Don't forget to add the class to the `directives:` of the element where you use the directive.

Comment: I understand the logic of your code Gunter but I think it doesn't quite fit. The class should be added to the parent element.

HTML:
    <div class="md-input-wrapper">
        <input type="text" class="md-input">
    </div>

This is what I am a little stuck on as I don't know how to reference a parent element of an element which the directive is triggered for?

Comment: Ok, but the parent is not the parent component, but the parent tag? In this case you'd need the `ElementRef`. There is no `closest()` in Angular. Would you still want to use that or is just `.parentElement` ok?

Comment: I have updated my question to show the HTML which the directive should be attached to in case it helps :)

Comment: I updated my question. Again, I hope I didn't add bugs while translating from Dart to TS.

Comment: Thanks Gunter. I would be happy if .parent works. Can you show how I would use it? Your code works in ts although book should be Boolean :)

Comment: What do you mean by " I would be happy if .parent works." and "Your code works ". Does it actually work but you want something slightly different?

Comment: I get the following errors:

EXCEPTION: Error during evaluation of "focus"
EXCEPTION: Error during evaluation of "blur"

Error: EXCEPTION: Error during evaluation of "blur"
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: view is undefined

Any thoughts ? Do I need to add some markup to the HTML ?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to previous answers, if you don't want to add a directive, for the specific component (you already have a directive for a parent component, you are using Ionic 2 page or something else), you inject the renderer by adding `private _renderer: Renderer` in the page constructor and update the element using the event target like this:

html:

```
(dragstart)="dragStart($event)"
```

TS:

```
dragStart(ev){
    this._renderer.setElementClass(ev.target, "myClass", true)
}
```

Edit: to remove the class just do:

```
dragEnd(ev){
    this._renderer.setElementClass(ev.target, "myClass", false)
}
```

Comment: Very concise answer and works great. The only change I would make is since it is typescript give "ev" an explicit type of "Event".
    dragStart(ev: Event){....

Answer (score 0):

The name of the selector has to be inside "[ ]", as shown below

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[.mdInput]',
  host: {
    '(focus)':'_setInputFocus(true)',
    '(blur)':'_setInputFocus(false)',
    '[class.md-input-focus]':'inputFocusClass'
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch the focus / blur events dynamiclly on every input on your component :

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  name = 'Angular focus / blur Events';

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
       // document.getElementsByTagName('input') : to gell all Docuement imputs
       const inputList = [].slice.call((<HTMLElement>this.el.nativeElement).getElementsByTagName('input'));
        inputList.forEach((input: HTMLElement) => {
            input.addEventListener('focus', () => {
                input.setAttribute('placeholder', 'focused');
            });
            input.addEventListener('blur', () => {
                input.removeAttribute('placeholder');
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Checkout the full code here :  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wtwpjr