# How to define the method on custom component? In AngularJS 2

Tags: typescript, angular

I was create my component(A). That is combine multiple html element.
and I have 2 question.

1. I don't know how defined method(get, etc..) on my component. I used @Output, @ViewChild, etc.. but it is not working. and I don't wanna develope this way. I need other way.
2. How can I find my component(A) at home component?

and other question..

1. how use component focus out event? what to use focus out keyword?
   (ngFocusOut)? (focusout)? (ngBlur)? (blur)? that is not working..

plz help me!!

Comment: See http://angular.io

Comment: 1&2, you are probably using angular2 the wrong way, it is a data-driven framework. Generally, components don't interact with each other, instead, they interact with services. 3, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34799667/angular2-on-focus-event-to-add-class) out and create a minimal example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522306/angular-2-focus-on-newly-added-input-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find you component A on home component by import it in home component

```
import {componentA} from '/componentA Path/'
```

About Focus Review this links [Angular 2: Focus on newly added input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522306/angular-2-focus-on-newly-added-input-element)

[Angular 2 set focus to another input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34799667/angular2-on-focus-event-to-add-class)

Comment: thank you for your answer. but I need the component Object. import my component and using <my-component name="abc" ></my-com~~> like this.. and I want abc component object..

Comment: After you import it you can use it by creating your object in home class 
`componentA_Obj : ComponentA;`

Comment: I know! but that is not <my-component name="abc" ></my-com~~>. that is new component A. I don't know how can i find that.

Comment: you can find your component on html by your selector that you declared in component directive in your home.ts component 
`@Component({
    selector : 'component-selector',})`
Then use it in home html component 
`<component-selector></component-selector>`

Comment: Right! So I use my component at home component. and I want that component-selector tag object! but i don't know!! How can i find that? T-T not HTML Elements object!

Comment: Ok, you should declare component-selector tag by your self in @component directive,

Comment: I will give you a complete example
`import {Component} from '@angular/core'
import {ComponentA} from 'ComponentA Path'

@Component({
    selector : 'CA-selector',
    })

export class ComponentA {}`
Then go to your root or home.ts
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ComponentA} from './componentA Path/'`
@Component({
    selector: 'home-app',
    template: `<div></div>
    <CA-selector></CA-selector>
    `,
    directives : [ComponentA]
})`

Comment: above comment to be more cleared

in componentA.ts


`import {Component} from '@angular/core'
import {ComponentA} from 'ComponentA Path'

@Component({
    selector : 'CA-selector',
    })

export class ComponentA {}`


Then go to your root or home.ts


`import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ComponentA} from './componentA Path/'
@Component({
    selector: 'home-app',
    template: '<div></div>
    <CA-selector></CA-selector>
    ',
    directives : [ComponentA]
})`

Comment: thanks your example. but.. sorry my English is not well. my source is exactly same your example. my question is use the <CA-selector></~> in home component. and run the constructor of ComponentA. constructor content is console.log(this);.

Comment: I wanna control this in console.log(this); from home component. so i need ComponentA object. are you know what i want that?

Comment: In your home.ts in your homeComponent 
1- Create obj from ComponentA
2-you can use it any where 
`export class homeComponent { 
CoA_obj : ComponentA; //create obj from Compnent A
yourFunction():void{console.log(this.CoA_obj );}}`
I hope answered your question.